# How to find the Minimum number of Non-intersecting Subsets with a Maximum Sum and Size

Tags: python, algorithm, set, set-theory

I am looking to find the minimum number of non-intersecting subsets (we will denote these `b_i`) of a set (we will denote `X`) such that all `b_i` satisfy the following constraints:

- Each element `x_i` of `X` should be placed into exactly one batch.
- `len(b_i) <= MAX_ELEMENTS_PER_BATCH` for all `i`
- `sum(b_i) <= MAX_SUM_PER_BATCH` for all `i`

I have come up with a heuristic for finding batches that satisfy the constraints but it doesn't guarantee the minimum number of batches.

For example:

1. Sort the collection.
2. Take the largest element and insert into your batch.
3. Fill the batch with the smallest elements until adding the next element would cause the batch sum to exceed `MAX_SUM_PER_BATCH`.
4. Remove the elements from this batch from the collection
5. Repeat steps 2-4 until there are no elements left.

I realize that this is probably a solved problem by some name I am not aware of and that optimizing for the minimum number of batches introduces complexity here.

Pseudo code, python or java in your answers, please.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

1. Sort the collection (largest to smallest)
2. Take the next element of the collection and try to fit it in the existing batches (starting with the first batch created) based on the 2 rules.
3. If it fits, add to batch and go back to 2. Otherwise create a new batch, add to it and go back to 2

I believe it satisfies all conditions, and only need 1 linear pass on the collection after sort

Edit: it may be more efficient also to store the current sum of the batch to not recompute it every time